# How to authenticate to Geonode api v2?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a geonode-project app and I want to authenticate to the Geonode API v2, but I cannot find an endpoint to authenticate.
I listed all endpoint of the api using http://localhost:8000/api/v2/ but I cannot find and endpoint to authenticate.
How can I authenticate to the Geonode REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Geonode support the authentication along with request.

Which endpoint you want to call?

Anyway iss enough to send the username and password as basic authentication along with your request.

Also with the barer token Is fine.